# Firefox 4.0.1 not displaying selected="selected"

Tags: php, html, firefox4

I have a form that I am trying to display. It seems to work fine in all browsers other than Firefox 4.0.1.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php $gender = 'Male'; ?>
        <select disabled="disabled" class="input-300 no-border" name="signup_gender" id="signup_gender" tabindex="40">
            <option value="-">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Female" <?php if($gender == 'Female'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >Female</option>
            <option value="Male" <?php if($gender == 'Male'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Male</option>
        </select>
```

Now in Firefox 4.0.1 this remains on the option "Select Gender", but every other browser including FF3.6 and lower displays the correct 'Male' option selected.

I have tried this with and without the `disabled="disabled"` part in there so it's not to do with that. Has anyone else experienced this issue, or know how to fix it?

EDIT:

The thing is that i can view the source code and it looks right.. its just not displaying... i mean i look at it and it looks like

```
        <select disabled="disabled" class="input-300 no-border" name="signup_gender" id="signup_gender" tabindex="40">
            <option value="-">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Female"  >Female</option>
            <option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option>
        </select>
```

but still isnt selecting Male

Comment: Remove all php and try to do that with plain html

Comment: Just tested in Firefox 4.0.1 - works as it should, select is disabled and displays 'male' option. I'd say validate your html code.

Comment: w3.org's validator seems to be down at the minute.. anyone know of one i can use to validate this?? ive encountered it several times before with FF on other sites no just my code :(

Comment: This AddOn is indispensable for me, it allows offline validation and validation of non public pages: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/html-validator/ . I'm using the SGML-Parser setting, to get the same results as the W3 parser.

Answer (score 3):

Try closing your browser window then relaunching the page.  I've found in Firefox that sometimes options are "sticky;" that is, it will keep the old setting even on page reloads.  Alternatively, you can hold down Ctrl and click the refresh button of press F5 to try to do a refresh-from-scratch.

If you had the option set to Select Gender and fixed your code, even if it's right, that could be your problem.

As a side note, if you have only two choices, have you considered a set of radio buttons instead of a drop-down listbox?  Fewer clicks = happier users.  :)

Comment: i always command shift r when developing for that reason.. the reason for the drop down is the visual consistency with the rest of the form..